# Insert multiple rows using EXISTS condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create an insert script to insert multiple rows and using "exists" condition, but it's returning me an error, and I don't know why,

I have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO films (id, code, title, did, date_prod, kind) VALUES
    (1, 'B6717', 'Tampopo', 110, '1985-02-10', 'Comedy'),
    (2, 'HG120', 'The Dinner Game', 140, DEFAULT, 'Comedy'),
    (3, 'HG770', 'The Tampopo', 140, DEFAULT, 'Comedy')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM films WHERE code in ('B6717', 'HG120', 'HG770') 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM films WHERE id in (1,2,3));
```

I would like to know why this query is not possible, and the correct way to insert multiple rows using multiple "exists" conditions

Comment: A WHERE clause is only valid following a SELECT.  If you want to do a conditional insert using just values, you will probably just need to wrap your INSERT statement in an "IF" - eg. IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM films WHERE code = 'B6717') ..... then do the B6717 insert

Comment: @Craig nice comment, do you know a way to use just a where condition?
I was oriented to not a condition for every row at my script, because I need to insert around 500k rows

Comment: Usually this is handled by a unique constraint, in combination with an ON CONFLICT handler. Could you share the DDL for the table? In your current INSERT it's still possible to insert multiple values, using concurrent inserts

Comment: @FrankHeikens I need to avoid conflicts at columns id and code, I have updated the script at my question

Comment: If you have 500k+ rows, then in reality it's probably going to be a heck of a lot easier to insert all of them into a temp/staging table first, and then you'd be able to build the conditional SELECT statement and use those records to insert into the table

Comment: For example, if you had a query like this: SELECT value1, value2 FROM staging_table s LEFT OUTER JOIN permanent_table t ON t.code = s.code WHERE t.id Is Null .... then that query would give you the basis of the records to be inserted into "permanent_table"

Comment: Please tell us what you **really** want to do. `EXISTS` is just a tool, not an objective. And possibly the wrong one. And always disclose your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do this is by placing a unique constraint on `code`:

```
ALTER TABLE films ADD UNIQUE (code);
```

Then you can use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`:

```
INSERT INTO films (id, code, title, did, date_prod, kind) VALUES
   (1, 'B6717', 'Tampopo', 110, '1985-02-10', 'Comedy'),
   (2, 'HG120', 'The Dinner Game', 140, DEFAULT, 'Comedy'),
   (3, 'HG770', 'The Tampopo', 140, DEFAULT, 'Comedy')
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz, that's part of what I need.

But I also need to avoid conflicts at id field

Comment: Simple - omit the conflict target.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the upsert operation to insert multiple rows without using the  EXISTS condition

The following query may help to insert multiple rows into your table.
The query is as follows :

```
INSERT INTO films (id, code, title, did, date_prod, kind) VALUES
  (1, 'B6717', 'Tampopo', 110, '1985-02-10', 'Comedy')
ON CONFLICT (code) DO UPDATE
  SET title = VALUES(title),
       did = VALUES(did),
       date_prod = VALUES(date_prod),
       kind = VALUES(kind);
```

The following query  will  attempt to insert a row into the films table with the specified values  and if there is a conflict it will perform an update on the conflicting row instead.